# validating xml using a tool in python - gather output

Tags: python, popen, os.system, xmllint

I have been trying to capture the output of this command, both by os.system and by os.popen, but I have been unsuccessful. I want to stop the command from throwing output on the console and instead capture the output either into a data structure or into a file, to further check and process it. 
it's using a simple tool, called xmllint. 
I tried

```
1. p = os.popen('xmllint --noout --relaxng /home/xxxxx_id/folder_xx/xxxx/xxx/rngfile.rng /home/xxxxx_id/folder_xx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/the_xmlfile_that_needstobe_validated.xml')

2.  os.system('xmllint --noout --dtdvalid ' + path to the xml + '> xmloutput')
```

both seems unsuccessful and gives output on my console instead of copying it into a file or a data structure. I need to validate more than 100 xmls, and should be able to check each outout individually.

Help?

Resolved with:

```
os.system('xmllint --noout --dtdvalid ' + path to the xml + '> xmloutput 2>&1')
```

Comment: `xmllint` is probably sending some diagnostic output to "standard error", which is separate from its dump of the parse tree to "standard output" which you've suppressed using `--noout`. In approach 2, try putting " 2>&1" on the end of the command. Or, if you want that diagnostic output to go to a different file, " 2>somewhereelse.txt". (Without the quotes.) For approach 1, you should really be using the `subprocess` module nowadays; that lets you do whatever you like with standard output and standard error.

Comment: haha. I tried '2>&1' and it worked, wanted to come back and edit my question with the solution, and you had given the same suggestion. thanks :-) gareth.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitly use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), This allows you to distinguish between `STDOUT` and `STDERR` and you can also check the return-code. Futhermore it's the prefered way of starting an application.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['xmllint', '--noout', '--dtdvalid', path], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print p.communicate()
```